# Open Barcode Scanner from WebView in Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

So I have a BarcodeScanner implemented in my iOS app and it works fine for when a user clicks on a field in the app, it opens the scanner and fills out the data. However, there is another part of the app with a WebView and in that WebView are fields that I would also like to trigger the BarcodeScanner in my app to open up and fill those out. I'm not sure where to get started with this, since I don't really do web development and I'm guessing it requires coding there? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which implements the BarcodeScanner (assuming you are either using a pod or an import in swift). Once you create that, you can connect it to how many pages/buttons you'd like. Initialise the web view, add a button, and choose your custom BarcodeScanner class to direct to the scanner in the app.

```
func stopLoading() {
    mWebView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.moveToVC()
}


func moveToVC()  {
    print("Write code where you want to go in app")
    // Note: [you use push or present here]
    let vc = 
      self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
      "storyboardID") as! YourViewControllerName
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: OK, yeah I have that implemented already, but thank you. I was asking more along the lines of an event in the webview triggering an action in the app that could then fill out a form in the webview. I think I got it with either a button outside the webview or have the event in the webview load a custom url that I can check for when it is being loaded and trigger the in-app event hat way.